# col-md-4 property in bootstrap 4 not working in my ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```
    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row card-deck">
    <% for(var i=0;i<campgrounds.length;i++){ %>
        <div class="card col-12 col-md-4">
        <img class="card-image-top" src="<%= campgrounds[i].image %>"  style=width:100%;height:350px;>
        <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title"><%= campgrounds[i].name %></h3> 
            </div>
        </div>
    <% }%>
</div>
</div>
```

Here "campgrounds" is a dictionary array with 2 properties("name" and image source). Now this array has 6 items and my col-md-4 should give 3 items in a row in resolutions of medium and above. But, this is not working and there are 12 items in a single row when in large/medium resolutions. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.card` in Bootstrap has its own flex properties which override `.col-*`

You need to add `.card` as a child div of `.col-md-4` and you will see the results.

```css
.col-md-4{ margin: 20px auto; } /* Or use my-* classes */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row card-deck">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-image-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%;height:350px;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Card Title</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-image-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%;height:350px;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Card Title</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-image-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%;height:350px;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Card Title</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-image-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%;height:350px;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Card Title</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-image-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%;height:350px;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Card Title</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-image-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%;height:350px;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">Card Title</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But that will just add 1 card in a row due to col-lg-12. I need 3 cards in a row and 3 below. I used col-md-4 for md and lg, col-12 for resolutions below md.

Comment: @DivyamMadhok Glad to help, keep coding :)

Comment: Yeah. Did it! Thanks again.